# how to get dataset path to include into readNetFromTensorflow()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, opencv

how do i include path of dataset to include in Net.readfromtensorflow. i keep getting error of UnsatisfiedLinkError. the dataset in placed in static directory. i quote from spring doc "By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext"

code used:

```
Net net = Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("/dataset/frozen_east_text_detection.pb");
```

full error:
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J

using spring boot 2.0
spring version 5.1
opencv 4.0.1

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so, please share your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Which maven dependency do you use? You can use the javacpp-presets for opencv (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv). Everything you have to do is to add the maven dependency (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv-platform) to your pom. The dependency includes the required system libs for each platform (windows, linux, mac ..). Before you use opencv (classes from the org.opencv package namespace) you have to call

`static {
        Loader.load(opencv_java.class);
    }`

After this call it should be possible to use the opencv api. The `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` should disappear. This error has nothing to do with spring. It's a problem with the libraries required for opencv which have to be loaded. To load the east_text_detection.pb file you can use something like this:

```
String location = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/dataset/frozen_east_text_detection.pb").toURI()).getPath();
Net net = Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(location);
```

This requires a directory 'dataset' with the .pb file. The dataset dir should be located directly under the resources dir.